# Несколько linearLayout в HorizontalscollBar?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Здесь не помещаются элементы, поэтому нужна горизонтальная прокрутка. Добавил. Но получилось для каждой строки в отдельности. А хотелось бы вставить **одну горизональную** прокрутку для всего активити. Попытался вставить несколько linearLayots в один HorizontalScrollView - не получается. Разве это нельзя сделать ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".ActivitySolar"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_solar">

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Минимальный расход воды" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="Name" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Qmin (л/с)" />

    </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Коэффициент  полезного  действия  микроГЭСа," />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="Name" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Н (м)" />

    </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @Jarvis_J ScrollView же ведь для вертикальной прокрутки ? мне этого не надо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте обернуть все ваши View в родительский Layout:

```
<HorizontalScrollView>
<FrameLayout>
... весь остальной код...
</FrameLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: при такой расстановке две строки оказываются на одной... Прям одна накладывается на другую.

Comment: Тогда вместо <FrameLayout> поиграться с другими: <LinearLayout orientation: vertical>

Comment: суть в том, чтобы все блоки обернуть в одного родителя, который, в свою очередь, находиться внутри <HorizontalScrollView>